# C: how to store a string

Tags: c

In c, there appears to be no way to store a string as a variable, how would one prompt the user for a string, and save it as one?

Apologies, I'm very new to C, so if this is a dumb question I am sorry.

Comment: If you know it is a trivial question, why not do some research?

Comment: What tutorial are you working with?

Comment: This is so simple is is covered in most books in C within the first chapter or two

Comment: [Brief Google search result](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)

Comment: Good online resource: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html. Feed a man a fish he's happy. Teach him to fish, he depletes the ocean.

Comment: @kuriouscoder not quite sure if depleting the ocean is a good thing :-)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers all, I need to learn more about c, I would think there should be an easier way to do this, but clearly there Isn't, so I'll keep learning. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for something like:

```
char line[LENGTH];
char *rp;

printf("Please enter string:");
fflush(stdout);
rp = fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
if (!rp) {
    /* End of file or error. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine using `char []` and `fgets()`:

```
char data[64];
if (fgets(data, sizeof data, stdin)) {
    // input has worked, do something with data
}
```

Comment: This won't work for storing a string entered in response to a prompt.

Comment: Can you explain the *

Answer (score 0):

Strings are stored as arrays of `char`, so you would need to allocate an array large enough to store the string (the sequence of character values plus a 0 terminator):

```
#define MAX_STRING_LEN 20
...
char response[MAX_STRING_LEN + 1]; // +1 for the 0 terminator
...
printf( "Gimme a string: " );
fflush( stdout );
fgets( response, sizeof response, stdin );
printf( "you entered: %s\n", response );
```